# Create value with prefix and auto increment in migration using laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I want to create a database table in laravel using migration, I have 4 columns in that table

```
1) ID(Auto-Increment, Primary Key)
2) Book Name
2) Book ID
4) Price
```

Now, I need to automatically fill value of BOOK ID column, value like this
Book ID = 'Book_1' (here "Book_" is prefix & 1 is value from ID column)

so for auto increment we create like this

```
$table->increments('id');
```

I need for BookID, how to write for that.

Comment: What have you tried already? Paste your code

Comment: I would just you to look for derived column. You can simply have that in your SELECT statement by prefixing "Book_" with id

Comment: Why do you have BookID column? If it's only for the presentational purpose then you can BookID while displaying the data.

Answer (score 0):

possible solution.

**NOTE : not in table creation (migration) but when actually storing data.**

create an ordinary varchar column to store name.

`$table->string('name');`

in the `AppServiceProvider` class `boot()` function. do something like this.
let's imagine your particular model is 'Book'

```
Book::created(function ($book) {
    $book->update(['name' => 'Book_' . $book->id]);
}
```

this will bind an event to the 'Book' creation. when every time new book is saved to the database, name will automatically generate and save.

Answer (score 0):

If the **`BookID`** column is only for the representational purpose you can add an accessor.

```
public function getBookIdAttribute()
{
    return 'Book_' . $this->attributes['id'];
}
```

else, you can accomplish by adding this to your model,

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function ($model) {
        $model->BookID = 'Book_' . $model->id;
        $model->save();
    });
}
```